# What is this book called? 汉说文

Tags: classical-chinese, dictionary

I am beginning Chinese speaker, but I watch this documentary on Chinese characters and they talk about origins of the characters from ideograms.  They refer to a book called "Roots of Characters" but I cannot find it.  Instead using Chinese Characters 汉说文 I find a website with some information: http://shuowen.xpcha.com/03ch6de8uu4.html Here is the entry for:  水 (shui : water)

[image]

What is the English name of this book?  Is there a reliable online resource?

Comment: I believe you are referring  to 说文, a dictionary originated from Han dynasty
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi

Comment: @SiyiDeng sure! looks great! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi

Answer (score 1):

The book is "说文解字", shorten as "说文".
汉 here means the time when it was written, the Han Dynasty; but not Chinese(汉语/汉文). People may refer it to "汉·说文" or just "说文".
You can get details here: [Wikipedia/Shuowen_Jiezi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)